# php adding field on the fly without defining them first

Tags: php, class, field, member

so  in php, you don't have define the field in a class first like java , is that correct??

in java you cannot say

```
public class javac {
    int x;
    int y;
    public javaC() {
     this.z = 3;
    }
 }
```

but in php can you say that?

```
class phpC {
$x;
$y;

public phpC() {
   $this->z = "omg"; 
 }
  }
```

what is php's documentation on this? and what is the correct term for such behaviour, i dont think it is called adding field on the fly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are correct.. You can assign a value to an uninitialized property in PHP.  Java is strict and PHP is loosey goosey :)

The technical name for this is "overloading."  Here is the documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php

Comment: +1 I would add that just because you aren't ***required*** to initialize the property doesn't mean it's not a good idea.

Comment: I could not agree more except in the case you are setting up an interface class.

Comment: *"an interface class"* ... your wording is a bit confusing ... an actual Interface cannot contain member variables and will generate an E_FATAL error if you try. Sorry for hassling you about it ... the answer is fine :)

Comment: oh crap.. you are kind because an "interface class" is completely wrong.  I meant a class intended to be overloaded, like purposefully overloading properties for MySQL column names in which you have no prior knowledge of what the column names are with the __set() function.  Is there a technical name for that?

Comment: when do we use __set() function then? seems it is same as the "overloading" approach

Comment: As for a `__set()` case I believe the correct term is still overloading. Generally I would call what you referred to as an "interface class" an abstract class. A class declared as abstract can't be instantiated itself but can provide concrete properties and methods for its child classes (which can be optionally overridden or extended as long as they aren't declared as `private`). You could define `__set` in the abstract class and then it would access the varying unknown property names in the same way in any child classes.

Comment: @user1118019 You can use or not use `__set` whenever you like. It simply exists as a go-between when attempting to assign a value to a class property that is inaccessible from the current scope. So, for example, you could assign values to protected or private object properties from outside the object by implementing `__set()`

Comment: There we go!  Thanks for setting both of us straight, although my bloated ego says, "yes, obviously I meant an abstract class" (not really, and thanks again).

Comment: @JamesL. Haha we all get the bloated ego syndrome on here sometimes. When I'm wrong or off-base and someone crucifies me for it I just try to remember it's all just to provide the best possible educational resource for people :)

Comment: @rdlowrey as long as I'm learning and not being berated by trolls I'm a happy camper :-)